# Use bash builtin `bind` command when starting chroot

Tags: bash, chroot, readline, shell-builtin, inputrc

I have a chroot and I want the chroot to have its own `.inputrc` file when it starts, and then run a program.

I'm used to starting the chroot with `chroot <PATH> <PROGRAM_TO_RUN>` so I tried

```
chroot <PATH> bind -f <PATH_IN_CHROOT>/.inputrc && <PROGRAM_TO_RUN>
```

but then I get the error:

```
chroot: failed to run command ‘bind’: No such file or directory
```

After reading the `readline` manual I saw `bind` was a `bash` builtin. So I tried using `builtin` to run the command like so:

```
chroot <PATH> builtin bind -f <PATH_IN_CHROOT>/.inputrc && <PROGRAM_TO_RUN>
```

but got the same error:

```
chroot: failed to run command ‘builtin’: No such file or directory
```

I know running two programs together via `&&` works for chroot because I tested with:

```
~# chroot <PATH> echo "yo" && echo "Hi"
yo
Hi
~#
```

I also know that the `bind` command and the `builtin` command work on their own inside the chroot:

```
~# chroot <PATH> bash
/# builtin -h
bash: builtin: -h: invalid option
builtin: usage: builtin [shell-builtin [arg ...]]
/# builtin bind -h
bash: bind: -h: invalid option
bind: usage: bind [-lpsvPSVX] [-m keymap] [-f filename] [-q name] [-u name] [-r keyseq] [-x keyseq:shell-command] [keyseq:readline-function or readline-command]
/# bind -h
bash: bind: -h: invalid option
bind: usage: bind [-lpsvPSVX] [-m keymap] [-f filename] [-q name] [-u name] [-r keyseq] [-x keyseq:shell-command] [keyseq:readline-function or readline-command]
```

**How can I run the `bind` command inside the `chroot` command so I can set a custom `.inputrc` for the chroot?**

Comment: Just set the `INPUTRC` environment variable to the path of your inputrc file inside the chroot: `INPUTRC=/path/to/inputrc chroot <jail> bash`

Comment: For the `INPUTRC` var, do I need the path to include the outside chroot part or is that path inside the chroot only?

Comment: The path is inside the chroot only.

Comment: For other commands, you should use `chroot <jail> bash --rcfile file` and put your commands inside `file` (its path is inside the chroot). If you have `/dev/` and `/proc` mounted inside the chroot you could also use `bash --rcfile <(echo 'cmd1; cmd2; ...')`.

Comment: Ooo good to know, I'll try that. I am in fact mounting those dirs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess:

You are trying to run a Bash built-in command in a chroot like this:

```
chroot <PATH> bind -f <PATH_IN_CHROOT>/.inputrc && <PROGRAM_TO_RUN>
```

But your chroot doesn't have any interpreter running, which could understand `bind`. Does the following work:

```
chroot <PATH> bash -c "bind -f <PATH_IN_CHROOT>/.inputrc && <PROGRAM_TO_RUN>"
```

PS
As `@mosvy` said, first as answer and then as comment, you can pass the environment with the call of chroot:

```
INPUTRC=/path/to/inputrc chroot <jail> bash
```

Comment: This does work. The solution above in @mosvy's  comment (`INPUTRC=/path/to/inputrc chroot <jail> bash`) also works. If you edit your answer to also include @mosvy's answer I will accept it. :)